# Changing value of registry key with getRuntime().exec(cmd) does not change registry value even the operation ended successfully

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, regedit

I'm trying to change registry value from my Java application. I use the command:

```
LoudnessEqualizationToggle.execCmdNoReturn("reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\MMDevices\\Audio\\Render\\"+guid+"\\FxProperties\""
                                           + " /f /v \"{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4\" /t REG_DWORD /d \""+((activateLEOnKey) ? 1 : 0)+"\"");
```

> Where guid is {d348b8e8-3118-4a9c-9b43-422647b555ca}
>
> activateLEOnKey is boolean value

**execCmdNoReturn** function:

```
public static final void execCmdNoReturn(String cmd)  {

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");

            System.out.println("Command:"+cmd);
            System.out.println("Printing executed data");

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(LoudnessEqualizationToggle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Everything works okay. I get output into command prompt:

> The operation completed successfully

**So I start *regedit* to verify if value has changed, but to my surprise nothing changed. The value is the same as before.**

**Do I have permissions? Yes**
I use a batch file to execute my application with **Run as administrator**.

**Batch file:**

```
cd %~dp0
java -jar LoudnessEqualizationToggle.jar
pause
```

Created shortcut from that and run as administrator.

**Are you owner of that key? Yes**

I tested my command and permissions with a batch file testing if the current value `0` in Windows registry can be changed to `1` as expected.

Batch file for that test is:

```
cd %~dp0
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{d348b8e8-3118-4a9c-9b43-422647b555ca}\FxProperties" /f /v "{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4" /t REG_DWORD /d "1"
net stop audiosrv //just restarting audio down here , not important
net stop AudioEndpointBuilder
net start audiosrv
net start AudioEndpointBuilder
pause
```

The value has changed in Windows registry after batch file execution from 0 to 1 (desired action).

So when I run my command from command prompt window directly, I can see the value changed. But when I run my command from runtime exec within my Java application, no value is changed in Windows registry, although I see that the command executed with no problem. And on my Java debug I see EXACTLY the same command being executed as I have in batch file.

**What could be the reason for not getting the registry value changed by reg.exe command executed from within my Java application?**

Process Monitor screen (after a tip by Mofi):

[image: Process Monitor log with filter set to include all registry access with MMDevices in path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WOW6432Node` in the log of **Process Monitor** indicates that the Java code is executed with 32-bit Java in a 32-bit environment on 64-bit Windows. Therefore the called `reg.exe` is also the 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe` which modifies therefore the DWORD value in `WOW6432Node`.

Microsoft articles with details about Windows On Windows:

- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)
- [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)
- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)

One solution working for 32-bit and 64-bit Java on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows would be:

1. Get string value of environment variable `SystemRoot`.
2. Check if file `SystemRoot + "\\Sysnative\\reg.exe"` exists.

   This is only the case for 32-bit Java executed on 64-bit Windows. In all other cases, i.e. 64-bit Java on 64-bit Windows or 32-bit Java on 32-bit Windows, this file does not exist because `Sysnative` does not exist. Yes, `Sysnative` does not exist for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows.
3. If the file `reg.exe` exists in `Sysnative` in Windows directory, call `SystemRoot + "\\Sysnative\\reg.exe"`.
4. Otherwise call `SystemRoot + "\\System32\\reg.exe"` which is the right executable for 64-bit Java on 64-bit Windows as well as 32-bit Java on 32-bit Windows.